# Comments grey in OpenOffice

Tags: windows, windows-xp, openoffice, comments

I want to read comments in documents someone else edited with Word and saved as rtf 
Everything shows except comments. The Comments option in my OpenOffice View menu is grey and so is the Comments option under Changes in the OO Edit menu. I can read the comments in my copy of MS Word (on a different computer). Tried OO's repair. Also tried to update OO but get the comment that OO cannot connect. How can I read those comments in OO? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The RTF converter into OpenOffice.org does not preserve comments.

Try saving as .doc instead of RTF to see if there is a better result.  That converter tends to be in better shape.

The latest stable version of OpenOffice.org is 3.3.0.  If you don't have that, go directly to http://openoffice.org for the download.

You *might* be able to overcome this problem by also installing LibreOffice, http://www.libreoffice.org/.  LibreOffice 3.4.3 may convert better in some cases.  It won't replace your OpenOffice.org setup and you can switch back and forth as useful.